# DataTables iusse with applying order

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

In my project I use datatable connected to MySQL databases to show some data. Everything works fine but one little thing. I need descending sorting over my ID column. So I am trying to apply "order" attribute like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable(
{     
 "order": [[0, 'desc']] 
 "language": {
 "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Polish.json"        
  }});
});
```

After doing that I certainly get table sorted by appropriate column, but I loose all the datatables features - normal table is the output. If I remove this order attribute, it gets back to normal.

Any advice in this matter?

Comment: You lack comma after  `"order": [[0, 'desc']]` ...@chris85, correcting **one** typo just for introducing a new one .. :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks a lot man! Beginner's mistake :)